# Why getQuery ignores soft deletes?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

In Laravel, when I use getQuery function to modify my query result based on  model, I'm getting all values including softdeleted. It literally forgets to include `and stock.deleted_at is null` in the query. Why? How can I make it filter out deleted records.

Model

```
class Stock extends Model
{
  use SoftDeletes;
  protected $dates = ['issue_date', 'expiry_date'];
...
```

Query (getting stock grouped by expiry_date)

```
$query = Stock::where('product_id', $id);
$query = $query->getQuery();
$query
    ->select(DB::raw(
        'count(*) as total, 
         DATE_FORMAT(IFNULL(`expiry_date`, "0000-00-00"),"%d-%m-%Y") AS expiry_date '
    ))
    ->groupBy('expiry_date');

$result = $query->get();
```

I had an idea of not using getQuery(), but in this case 'issue_date' will give me an error message saying "laravel Data missing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$query->toBase()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7b3bf0ba3a8b7c501a2d357afb00b1492b055c3c/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L1133-L1141) instead of [`$query->getQuery()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7b3bf0ba3a8b7c501a2d357afb00b1492b055c3c/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L1110-L1118).

```php
$results = Stock::where('product_id', $id)->toBase()->selectRaw('
    count(*) as total, 
    DATE_FORMAT(IFNULL(`expiry_date`, "0000-00-00"),"%d-%m-%Y") AS expiry_date
')->groupBy('expiry_date')->get();
```

The `getQuery` method simply returns the underlying query, whereas `toBase` first applies all global scopes (soft deletes is implemented as a global scope).

---

BTW, you can call `select` and `groupBy` directly on the Eloquent query itself:

```php
$results = Stock::where('product_id', $id)->selectRaw('
    count(*) as total, 
    DATE_FORMAT(IFNULL(`expiry_date`, "0000-00-00"),"%d-%m-%Y") AS expiry_date
')->groupBy('expiry_date')->get();
```

...though that would return partial Eloquent models, which is not always a great idea.

Comment: returning partial eloquent model is not a good idea for me, because I cast 'issue_date' to a Carbon instance in my model, and current selection does not include this field.